# Google play GamesClient error 6500

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am getting a 6500 error and this is what the docs have to say about it.

```
public static final int STATUS_MATCH_ERROR_INVALID_PARTICIPANT_STATE

One or more participants in this match are not in valid states.
This could occur if a specified participant is not actually a participant of the match, or is invalid, or is in an incorrect state to make the API call.
Check the logs for more detailed information.

Constant Value: 6500 (0x00001964)
```

Can anyone elaborate on other reasons for this error?

EDIT: Elaboration.

I start a **TurnBasedMatch** and I start taking turns using **GamesClient.takeTurn()**. After two turns my app crashes due to a null pointer exception. My TurnBasedMatch object becomes null because I get an error with status code 6500. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: please Add more explanation to your qurey

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I tried to add a bit more

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it. I was passing in the wrong pending participant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once **Check your pending participant**.
You might be passing wrong pending participant..